# How do you set up Gradle properly and create a new Gradle project for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, installation, gradle

So, I downloaded Gradle but I don't know how to set it up correctly. After I unzipped the zip file, what do I do next? I want to use Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA. From a livestream I've seen I know that there's a **settings.gradle** and a **build.gradle** file in the project folder in IntelliJ.

Also, I've seen that they used the windows console.

First of all, how do I access gradle through the windows console and tell it to generate a new project for IntelliJ?

As you can see, I don't have any experience with Gradle. Unfortunately I can't really find out how to use it.

I want the IntelliJ project then to have [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) and Slick.

Additionally, I know what it says in the **build.gradle** file I've seen on the livestream (I only want to create my project with the same structure like theirs).

Can anybody give a detailed description of what to do to achieve all this?

Comment: Gradle has a documentation page, containing a "Getting Started" chapter. Have you read it? http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorials.html#N100CB

Comment: Besides the user guide, also check out the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: I read the part about Installing before, but some points don't seem clear to me. Unpacking, for instance. It tells me what the single zips contain, but not how to make them accessible in the console. and I do not understand how to set the GRADLE_HOME...They say something about PATH, but where do I find that?

Comment: Ouch. Then you need some help about Windows, not about Gradle. I'll give an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I didn't do much with such things before. Well, there's always a first time...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Lets' say you unpacked gradle to `d:\tools\gradle`.

To add its bin directory it to the PATH in a console window, execute the following command:

```
set PATH=d:\tools\gradle\bin;%PATH%
```

The above prepends the bin path to the current value of the PATH environment variable. This will only change the path for this specific command window.

If you want to add it to the PATH globally, then go to your control panel and choose *System*, then *Advanced parameters* (it might be something a little bit different: I'm translating from my French version of Windows). Then in the Advanced system parameters tab, click the button *Environment variables...*. Find the *Path* environment variable in the list, and add the directory, separated from the others using a semicolon (`;`).

Note: you can also define a new environment variable called GRADLE_HOME:

```
set GRADLE_HOME=d:\tools\gradle
```

or globally, as explained above, and reference it inside the PATH variable:

```
set PATH=%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: Does Gradle (or any other application) actually uses `GRADLE_HOME` or it is just used to define the path?

Comment: GRADLE_HOME is not defined on my system and I use gradle all the time so I guess noone really cares

Answer (score 4):

Just intall [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Then you can just open the terminal and install easy like:

```
brew install gradle
```

Done! It's installed!

For test just type in your terminal:

```
gradle -v
```

And you'll have something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-09-14 07:26:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.1 x86_64
```

Then, open your IntelliJ and create a new gradle project as normal, just setting the gradle's path when necessary (normally in /usr/local/Cellar when installed with homebrew or /opt when installed other ways).

Good luck!

Comment: installed with homebrew however it didn't work with intelliJ. is it /usr/local/Cellar or /usr/local/Cellar/gradle ?? Also when we install gradle with homebrew do we still need to GRADLE_HOME?

Comment: @user1870400 /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/<version>/libexec

Comment: Could you please explain what homebrew does under the hood? in case some day it also become commercial and you have to pay to use it

Answer (score 1):

For linux Users,
User SDK Man to easily manage your gradle installation and path settings for development as well as gradle update

[GET SDK MAN HERE](http://sdkman.io/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

(for mac os users) Let's assume, you unpacked zip file into */Users/onuryilmaz/gradle-3.3* folder. Then open terminal and define a new environment variable called GRADLE_HOME:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/onuryilmaz/gradle-3.3
```

After that reference it inside the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

just update the brew  and install and set path that's all

1. brew update && brew install gradle
2. export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.1.1/bin
3. https://gradle.org/install/